# jQuery to add CSS class to selected radio button

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I am trying to add a CSS class to a radio button based on which radio button is selected.

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function() {
  var radVal = $("input[type=radio][name=align]").val();
  if (radVal == 'center') {
    $(".tlt1").addClass('centerCssClass').change();
    $(".tlt1").removeClass('topCssClass').change();
  } else if (radVal == 'top') {
    $(".tlt1").addClass('topCssClass').change();
    $(".tlt1").removeClass('centerCssClass').change();
  }
});
```

```css
.centerCssClass {
  background-color: blue;
}

.topCssClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div class="tlt1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly the selector you're retrieving the value from is incorrect. You should use the `this` reference to get the value from the clicked radio button.

Secondly you need to make the CSS classes more specific so that they override the original `background-color` setting of `.tlt1`. Try this:

```js
var $tlt = $(".tlt1");

$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function() {
  var radVal = $(this).val();
  if (radVal == 'center') {
    $tlt.addClass('centerCssClass').removeClass('topCssClass');
  } else if (radVal == 'top') {
    $tlt.addClass('topCssClass').removeClass('centerCssClass')
  }
});
```

```css
.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.tlt1.centerCssClass {
  background-color: blue;
}

.tlt1.topCssClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div class="tlt1"></div>
```

Note that you also don't need to trigger the `change()` event on the `div` elements as it's redundant.

Comment: Thank you @Rory for a detailed explanation. This answer has resolved my question and given me in-depth knowledge on the issue posted. Thanks bro.

Comment: That's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:checked` selector to get *selected* radio button value and slightly change the CSS class declaration to override the `background-color`

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function() {
  var radVal = $("input[type=radio][name=align]:checked").val();
  if (radVal == 'center') {
    $(".tlt1").addClass('centerCssClass').removeClass('topCssClass');
  } else if (radVal == 'top') {
    $(".tlt1").addClass('topCssClass').removeClass('centerCssClass');
  }
});
```

```css
.tlt1.centerCssClass {
  background-color: blue;
}

.tlt1.topCssClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div class="tlt1">tlt1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Satpal for posting a detailed answer. Thank you for your time and have a great day bro :)

Comment: @pv619, Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

because tlt1's background color can't be covered

so you have to add `!important` after centerCssClass,topCssClass css

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function() {
  var radVal = $(this).val();
  var tlt1 = $("#tlt1");
  if (radVal == 'center') {
    tlt1.addClass('centerCssClass').change();
    tlt1.removeClass('topCssClass').change();
  } else if (radVal == 'top') {
    tlt1.addClass('topCssClass').change();
    tlt1.removeClass('centerCssClass').change();
  }
});
```

```css
.centerCssClass {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

.topCssClass {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div id='tlt1' class="tlt1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @IT for providing help on the CSS. I have added `!important` to the CSS. Thank you and have a great day :)

Comment: @pv619, using `!important` is bad practice and it should be avoided, see mine or Rory's answer and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: it's my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution is correct**, just inside `change` event change `var radVal = $("input[type=radio][name=align]").val();` to `var radVal = $(this).val();`

Because right now you get value of first element that is an `input` has attribute `type='radio'` and `name='align'`. So first element in your case has value center, so it is always center. And by using `$(this)` you get the element that was actually changed.

**Also** you do not have to trigger `change()` event on your `.tlt1` element.

**Lastly** in your css the value that is lower is more respected than the one higher. That is why your background did not change. Because background for class `.tlt1` was more important than to class `centerCssClass`.

**Here is an working example**

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function () {
    var radVal = $(this).val();
    if (radVal == 'center') {
        $(".tlt1").addClass('centerCssClass');
        $(".tlt1").removeClass('topCssClass');
    } else if (radVal == 'top') {
        $(".tlt1").addClass('topCssClass');
        $(".tlt1").removeClass('centerCssClass');
    }
});
```

```css
.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.centerCssClass {
  background-color: blue;
}

.topCssClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div class="tlt1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro for an in depth answer on the `$this` value. It made a lot of sense and helped me gained more information of the issue. Have a great day bro :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

use `id` instead of `class` `tlt1`

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=align]").on('change', function() {
  var radVal = $(this).val();
  if (radVal == "center") {
    $("#tlt1").removeClass('topCssClass').change();
    $("#tlt1").addClass('centerCssClass').change();
    $("#tlt1").removeClass('tlt1');
  } else {
    $("#tlt1").removeClass('centerCssClass').change();
    $("#tlt1").addClass('topCssClass').change();
    $("#tlt1").removeClass('tlt1');
  }
});
```

```css
.centerCssClass {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.topCssClass {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.tlt1 {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="center">Center<br>
<input type="radio" name="align" value="top">Top<br>
<div class="tlt1" id="tlt1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro your answer and have a great day :)